# Storing base data types as char[] instead of uints

Tags: c++, padding, reinterpret-cast

We are considering setting all our base types for our datatypes as char[] instead of uints to avoid padding issues in our structs (reading in external binary data)

Is there any difference in speed between calling get() for these 2? Any other issues that might arise?

Not 100% sold on the solution, but cant seem to avoid doing this without putting in #pragma pack(1) everywhere!

```
struct U64BigEndianPacked
{
    const char value[ sizeof( uint64_t ) ];

    const uint64_t operator()() const
    {
        return _byteswap_uint64( *reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t* const>( &value[ 0 ] ) );
    }
};
```

or

```
struct U64BigEndian
{
    uint64_t value;

    uint64_t get() const
    {
        return _byteswap_uint64( value );
    }
};
```

Edit:

To provide more information, we are receiving a char* data stream from an external program, which is a binary stream of data. On our end we have a series of structs which we want the data stored in (multiple members variables of chars, strings, and ints), however due to padding, calling

```
        pMsgData = reinterpret_cast<DATA_STRUCT*>( data );
```

fails due to the struct misaligning when the ints are taken into consideration.

Potentially could write functions to do individual taking data into each member of each struct, but there are so many of them that this would be far more time consuming and we want to avoid this.

Comment: the first one is allowed to crash or give wrong answers if not aligned? and it's also missing a * - two of them actually

Comment: This sounds like a really bad plan. Why can't you handle this in a well-defined serialization/deserialization stage? This is a process you want to perform as few times as possible. Here you're going to be doing it constantly, on everything, forever.

Comment: Unless you are using C++20, and only then you have to use [implicit lifetime types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ImplicitLifetimeType), this code has undefined behavior as `reinterpret_cast` does not create objects

Comment: @user253751  updated the code to what actually would use. Do your points remain?

Comment: The first one is still allowed to crash or give wrong answers if not aligned. Whereas the compiler aligns the second one so it won't do that.

Comment: the memory that the reinterpret_cast is applied to is always an array of bytes with no padding applied as it's serialised data so misalignment is not a worry

Comment: @jp94 `const char value[ sizeof( uint64_t ) ]` doesn't look properly aligned to me.

Comment: @jp94 Pretty sure they are more concerned with the alignment of the array object itself.  Since it is a char array it can start at any address, where a `uint64_t` has a stronger alignment requirement and the array could be unaligned to that alignment.

Comment: I don't understand.  Why not have the classes write to the file instead of an external entity?  In my serialization code, I have the class write to a `uint8_t` buffer, read from a `uint8_t` buffer and also return the size it would occupy in the buffer.  This allows for creation of I/O buffer and use block I/O operations.  Search the internet for "C++ serialization".

Comment: this is all wire data and for more context - the U64BigEndian type above would be used as part of a larger struct which itself represents the full byte array. we can't see how doing the above is different from using #pragma pack(1)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews so there is no "file" so to speak. Recieve a feed of char* in a certain binary format, and want it inside of a struct that matches that format. However doing a reinterpret cast on the whole struct fails due to alignment of uints, so the idea was to change to char[] to get rid of our alignment problem

Comment: Added an edit to explain the situation more clearly

Comment: To extract the bytes, you'll want to `uint64_t value; std::memcpy(&value, &raw[position], sizeof value);`.

Comment: but thats much more expensive than a reinterpret cast and still has the padding issues

Comment: @Morten Look at the optimized assembly code. The `memcpy` will be just as expensive as it has to be to guarantee that the program has defined behavior. If the `memcpy` is not needed it may do a machine code version of `reinterpret_cast` instead. If it's needed, well, then it **is** needed. What padding issues would a `memcpy` have? You `memcpy` exactly the bytes needed into or from the variable you want to deserialize/serialize.

Comment: All uint64_t's have to be 64-bit aligned. No exceptions. If you read one that isn't aligned, you may get the wrong answer or crash. Except I lied - there is one exception. The exception is if you tell the compiler that it might not be aligned. For example by using #pragma pack(1).